# Prove $U(|f|, P)-L(|f|, P) \le U(f, P) - L(f, P)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This was one of the problems I had on an exam and it's been bothering me because I couldn't figure it out. I was only able to show $-L(|f|, P)\le-L(f, P)$ and $U(f, P)\le U(|f|, P)$, but adding the inequalities doesn't give the desired result.

"Let $f$ be a bounded integrable function on $[a,b]$. Let $P=\{x_0, ..., x_n\}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Prove that $U(|f|, P)-L(|f|, P) \le U(f, P) - L(f, P)$."

Here are the relevant definitions:

$\Delta x_i =x_i -x_{i-1}$

$M_i(f, P)=\text{sup}\{f(x): x\in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\}$

$m_i(f, P)=\text{inf}\{f(x): x\in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\}$

$U(f, P)= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}M_i(f, P)\Delta x_i$

$L(f, P)= \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}m_i(f, P)\Delta x_i$

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the reverse triangle inequality $|\,|f(u) - |f(v)|\,| \leqslant |f(u) - f(v)|$.

Hence, for any partition interval $I_j = [x_{j-1},x_j]$ we have

$$M_j(|f|,P)- m_j(|f|,P) = \sup_{u,v \in I_j}|\,|f(u)| - |f(v)|\,| \leqslant \sup_{u,v \in I_j}|f(u) - f(v)| = M_j(f,P)- m_j(f,P),$$

and

$$U(|f|,P) - L(|f|,P) = \sum_{j=1}^n(M_j(|f|,P)- m_j(|f|,P)) \Delta x_j \leqslant \sum_{j=1}^n(M_j(f,P)- m_j(f,P)) \Delta x_j\\ = U(f,P) - L(f,P)$$

Comment: Man, working under pressure really makes you forget about the little things. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostyOcean: You're welcome.